# Changing KML Files Contents

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am just wondering if there is a possibility that my program can add/remove markers in the kml file that I just created?

For example, my KML file contains all the areas in a city where there is a reported case of flooding. After uploading the file and displaying it in the Google Maps through my website, a new case was reported. Is it possible to add that place in my website's "add area" field and update the KML file as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries out there for programatically updating KML. My current favorite is [pyKML](http://packages.python.org/pykml/), but there's also [libkml](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/) and a number of others. Or just as easily, KML is just XML markup so any libraries you have for reading/writing XML work fine.

If you're asking can it be done through the Google Maps API, no it can't. The KML rendering there happens server side and you don't get write access to a KML object through KMLLayer.

Comment: to make things clearer, these libraries are different programs which I cannot include in the program? In other words, is it still possible for the user to just input an area in the field of my site and be able to update the output of the map through the kml?

Comment: These libraries are code that you can incorporate into your own code. So you would create an interface that takes input from your user and modifies the KML file.

Comment: thanks but i am not familiar with python programming language

Comment: i found some other libraries.. like this article below. thanks for the tip! http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html

Comment: Check out who authored that article.